# Border around table but not cells

Tags: html

Is there a way to display an HTML table with a border around the entire table but not around the cells within it? The table border attribute is deprecated in favor of CSS, but both the border attribute and the suggested CSS replacement outline the individual cells as well as the table.

Comment: Then you should show your `css` rules and the html code of the `table`, without that it is not possible to tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<table style="border:1px solid;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U2e8b/

Answer (score 5):

The HTML attribute `border` draws borders around the entire table as well as around each cell. The latter can be prevented using the attribute `rules` (which controls the existence of borders around cells) with value `none`:

```
<table border=1 rules=none>
```

Although the questions is not tagged with “css”, you might be interested in a CSS approach. The key issue is then to set the `border` property `table` element only. This does *not* create borders around cells. So you could use, in CSS,

```
table { border: solid thin gray }
```

for example, if you want all tables to have borders.

However, if some *other* style sheets set borders around cells and you don’t want them, you need to analyze how they do that and either edit them or write your own rules that have higher specificity and set e.g. `border: none` on `th` and `td+ elements.

Comment: rules=none didn't work for me - still border around cells

Comment: Also, border=1 didn't work either: needed border=1px